# Nodelet Publisher

Tags: ros, roscpp, publisher, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 virtual void onInit()
{
    ros::NodeHandle & private_nh = getPrivateNodeHandle();
    pub = private_nh.advertise<nodelet_test::buff>("chatter2", 10);
    nodelet_test::buff buffer;
    buffer.buffer_data.push_back(20);
    while(ros::ok())
    {
        pub.publish(buffer);
    }

}
```

I have the example code above for nodelet publisher only. Since I do not use callbacks (no subscriber ), is the way its done ? adding while loop inside onInit () ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248378/nodelet-publisher/) by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2016-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reading the documentation of [onInit](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet#onInit) it should not block. Basically it prevent the surrounding nodelet manager to continue initializing the other nodelets.

Instead you should create a timer in the `onInit` function and then publish your message in the triggered callback of the timer.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) on 2016-11-20**:
I would require 36Hz frequency of published messages, do you advice using a timer ? or do you see any problems arising ?

**Comment by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) on 2016-11-21**:
As you suggested I used createTimer and in that i could specify the frequency using ros::Duration